# I want to get the value with round but not getting proper result

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-11

I want to get the result with round the value please see the attached image. What is wrong with it.

The result should be : 18.59

[image: round problem]

I have used float instead of double.

MRE:

```
    float value = 18.585f;
    System.out.println(((float)Math.round(value * 100))/100);
```

Observed output:

> 18.58

Comment: System.out.println((float)Math.round(18.585*100)/100); Returning 18.59 for me

Comment: double value = 18.585; System.out.println(((double)Math.round(value * 100))/100); prints 18,59..........

float value = 18.585f; System.out.println(((double)Math.round(value * 100))/100); prints 18,58

Comment: @Petr F. I have used float instead of double.

Comment: with float I get same results:double value = 18.585; System.out.println(((float)Math.round(value * 100))/100); prints 18,59.......... float value = 18.585f; System.out.println(((float)Math.round(value * 100))/100); prints 18,58

Comment: I downvoted because you didn’t paste your code as text and because you didn’t give us a [mre]. It’s good that you have given us the expected result. We also need the observed result.

Comment: you just need to make sure value in *value* is double as @PetrF mention before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Ole V.V. I have not got any solution yet. Can you please help me to get 18.59 as a result. What should I do?

Comment: I got the solution by applying the BigDecimal. Thanks buddy I appreciate your effort. Thank you. Have great life ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem

The problem is not in the rounding. The problem is in the value that you are rounding. You think the value is 18.585. It is not. `float` values are not precise. The real value in your `float` variable is somewhere around 18.584999 because a `float` hasn’t got a better precision. The correct rounding of this value to two decimal places is 18.58. The result you got.

(Except you got 18.5799999237060546875 because the new value isn’t precise either; but in printed as 18.58.)

### A couple of possible solutions

The solution? There are many. I will present two.

1. Add a small value (sometimes referred to as an epsilon) to your value before rounding.
2. Use `BigDecimal` instead of `float`.

**Add an epsilon**

Let’s declare:

```
private static final float EPSILON = 0.000_001f;
```

And use it:

```
    float value = 18.585f;
    System.out.println(((float) Math.round((value + EPSILON) * 100)) / 100);
```

Output is the desired:

> ```
> 18.59
> ```

For values not ending in `5` adding the epsilon will not make any change to the rounded value, so only in weird corner cases does this approach risk giving undesired results.

**Use BigDecimal**

A `BigDecimal` holds the full precision of a decimal number no matter how many decimals you give it.

```
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("18.585");
    BigDecimal roundedValue = value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(roundedValue);
```

> ```
> 18.59
> ```

I am specifying `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` to make sure that rounding of 18.585 goes up to 18.59, not down to 18.58.

It’s crucial to use the constructor that takes a `String` argument so we also pass the full precision of your number into the `BigDecimal`. If we just passed the `float` to the `BigDecimal`, the imprecision would go along. Just to deter you, see how this fails:

```
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(18.585f);
    System.out.println(value);
    BigDecimal roundedValue = value.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(roundedValue);
```

> ```
> 18.58499908447265625
> 18.58
> ```

It was suggested in the comments that you could use `double` instead of `float`. `double` has a much better precision. Actually `float` has got a bad reputation. `double` still isn’t fully precise, so while they seem to fix the problem with 18.585, you risk running into the same problem with some other value.

### Link

Related question with a lot of good information: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I got the solution by applying the BigDecimal. Thank you.